# what's the difference between money raised in an ipo and its valuation?

Tags: ipo

I see news that says "company X wants to raise 3 million dollars at a valuation of 25 million dollars". How does the company get this 3 million? And is the valuation determined in part by how much many it wants to raise? If so: how?

Comment: Can you link a specific article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A company generally sells a *portion* of its ownership in an IPO, with  existing investors retaining some ownership.  In your example, they believe that the entire company is worth $25MM, so in order to raise $3MM it is issuing stock representing 12% of the ownership stake (3/25), which dilutes some or all of the existing stockholders' claims.